# VB.Net Initialising an array on the fly

Tags: vb.net, arrays

I wrote this - very simple - function, and then wondered does VB have some pre-built functionality to do this, but couldn't find anything specific.

```
Private Shared Function MakeArray(Of T)(ByVal ParamArray args() As T) As T()
    Return args
End Function
```

Not so much to be used like

```
Dim someNames() as string = MakeArray("Hans", "Luke", "Lia")
```

Because this can be done with

```
Dim someNames() as string = {"Hans", "Luke", "Lia"}
```

But more like

```
public sub PrintNames(names() as string)
   // print each name
End Sub

PrintNames(MakeArray("Hans", "Luke", "Lia"))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Any reason not to do:

```
Dim someNames() as string = New String(){"Han", "Luke", "Leia"}
```

The only difference is type inference, as far as I can tell.

I've just checked, and VB 9 has [implicitly typed arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms364068(v=vs.80)) too:

```
Dim someNames() as string = { "Han", "Luke", "Leia" }
```

(This wouldn't work in VB 8 as far as I know, but the explicit version would. The implicit version is necessary for anonymous types, which are also new to VB 9.)

Comment: Excellent, first example is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: I think we can all agree that the most important thing here is the correct spelling of "Han" :)

Comment: @Andy wrong, its the order in which they appear....it should be "Luke", "Han", and then "Leia"....cause we all know that Han and Leia belong closer together and not separated by her brother ;)

Answer (score 7):

```
Dim somenames() As String = {"hello", "world"}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following codes will work in VB 10:

```
Dim someNames = {"Hans", "Luke", "Lia"}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee336123.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
PrintNames(New String(){"Hans", "Luke", "Lia"})
```

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft recommends the following format

```
Dim mixedTypes As Object() = New Object() {item1, item2, itemn}
```

per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/8k8021te(v=VS.80).aspx

Note, you don't have to specify the size of new Array, as that is inferred from the initialized count of args. If you do want to specify the length, you specify not the "length" but index number of last space in array. ie. New Object(2) {0, 1, 2} ' note 3 args.

Comment: This is the explicit declaration format, suggest by MS.  The implied format is without the class `Object` defined and assumed.  BUT, should you have `Option Explicit` set, then you HAVE to have `Object` defined in the statement.