# How do you create a New array in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [VB.Net Initialising an array on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638216/vb-net-initialising-an-array-on-the-fly)

This maybe a stupid question, but its got me exasperated. How do I declare a new array inline? Is this possible? I've tried all of the following and they all don't work.

```
myVar = {"a", "b", "c"}
myVar = Array(3)
myVar = Array("a", "b", "c")
myVar = New Array()
myVar = New Array(3)
myVar = New Array("a", "b", "c")
```

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/638216/vb-net-initialising-an-array-on-the-fly

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Either

```
Dim strings = New String() {"a", "b", "c"}
```

or

```
Dim strings() As String = {"a", "b", "c"}
```

should work

Comment: Thanks! Wish the editor Error reporting told me that I had to explicitly define {} arrays.

Comment: Correct answer!

Note: In VB10, you may even just write { "a", "b", "c" }