# ArrayList declaration in VB with or without New keyword

Tags: vb.net

With the following Visual Basic Class:

```
Public Class Student
  Public Property StudentName As String
  Public Property Scores As Integer()
End Class
```

The following example line of code was provided by a textbook I'm reading:

```
arrList.Add(New Student With {.StudentName = "name", .Scores = New Integer() {98, 92, 81, 60}})
```

But this line of code without the 'New Integer()' declaration seems to work just fine:

```
arrList.Add(New Student With {.StudentName = "name", .Scores = {98, 92, 81, 60}})
```

I don't understand why I would need to use the 'New Integer()' declaration.  Is there something else happening with the 'New Integer()' declaration in this case, or was it unnecessary code?

Comment: What version of VB.net are you using?

Comment: Similar to this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/990524/231316

Comment: If you were using VS2008 then the example as written in the textbook would be required.

Comment: Using VB 2013 but text was VB 2008, so VS2008 comment very helpful to understand why I could omit the 'New'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an integer is a primitive type (bytes of data in a memory address), you don't need to declare it as `New`. when you type `Dim x As Integer = 0`. ;p an array is also a type: bunch of pointers to memory addresses.

you use the `New` operator to create an instance of an Object, using its `CTOR`. needed to initialize the object to a working state. for primitive types, not calling `New` simply results in the object being set to `Nothing`, just like classes - a reference type. however, the value of a primitive can simply be assigned to, since the memory has already been allocated. However, in the case of a class, the memory is not allocated since it's impossible to know the size of all the object pointers and types.

if you use the `New` operator on a primitive type, a new instance of that type will be created, initialized with an empty value, ie: 0 or "", instead of `Nothing`. This is done via the Class, not the Type.

As an example, here is the [String Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/system.string.aspx), and there is the [String Data Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thwcx436.aspx), which is an array of Characters. (actually, in dotnet, strings aren't even an array, they're just sequential series of bytes, although some types of implicit conversions from int use the array method).

also, i should mention, using the `New` operator creates the object on the heap, while creating only a pointer on the stack. not using the `New` operator with a primitive in a method will result in it being allocated to the stack.

edit: ah, but to address you specific use-case, it's better to use `New`, since you're using it outside the function (adding it as a member of some object), which is going to incur a copy operation to the heap anyways. only use primitives in methods if you're going to consume them immediately, otherwise, putting them on the stack is counter-productive.

Comment: These comments and the responses above explain clearly why I should use 'New' even if I could 'get away with out it'.

Comment: for most intents and purposes, you should alloc most of your types/objects on the heap. except ie: `For x = 1 To 3`. <- implicitly created on the stack, or for other items you will consume on the stack, etc... however, as stated, if declaring a primitive as a member variable of some object (not in a method), it's unnecessary to 'type' `New`, as that is implied. an object has no stack; a method does (CTOR included). creating stuff on the heap has an overhead and couple function pointer calls.

Comment: Excellent tutorial reminder of difference between heap/stack, and a better when/why New should be considered.  Thx.

Answer (score 2):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx#BKMK_Populating

> When you create an array by using an array literal, you can either supply the array type or use type inference to determine the array type. The following code shows both options.

```
Dim numbers = New Integer() {1, 2, 4, 8}
Dim doubles = {1.5, 2, 9.9, 18}
```

Comment: that occurs with most other data types in dotnet as well. it's called a narrowing/widening conversion. actually, more of an implicit conversion. the same as typing `Dim s As String`, `s = 15`. implicitly converted to string.

Comment: Great link to explain how widening applies when 'New' is not used.